# openlayer 6, geojson how to label a feature if it is a number/float/integer?

Tags: integer, label, geojson, openlayers-6

I have a geojson file with polygons all set-up.
It is no problem to display the name (a String) of the area in the middle of the polygon with this line:

```
geojsonStyle.getText().setText(feature.get('Area_name'));
```

but now I want to display the feature containing a float or integer in the Polygon as a label. I just thought to change the `"Area_name"` with the feature containing the number, for example: `'Shops in area'`.

so it would look like this:

```
geojsonStyle.getText().setText(feature.get('Shops in area'));
```

but this doesn't work.

I think it has something to do with the data-type (`string` vs `integers` vs `float`) and I need to make javascript to treat the number as a string. But I can't find anything about it in the examples. I think I overlook it? I hope someone can give me a hint in the right direction?

This feature contains only whole numbers, so it would be nicer if the .0 is not displayed. But another feature in this json file contains the percentages so the 2 decimals are relevant to display in the label.

this is how a part of the data looks like in the geojson file:

```
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Area_name": "Haarlem", "Shops in area": 1727.0]},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to coerce that number to a string: `geojsonStyle.getText().setText(""+feature.get('Shops in area'));`

If you don't want the zero, call `parseInt` or `toFixed(0)` on the number ([`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) will result in a string).

**code snippet:**

```js
var json = {"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Area_name": "Haarlem", "Shops in area": 1727.0 } }]}

console.log(json.features[0]["properties"]["Shops in area"]);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=parseInt(json.features[0]["properties"]["Shops in area"]);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks Geocodezip. This does the trick and was exactly what I was looking for:
One option is to coerce that number to a string:

```
geojsonStyle.getText().setText(""+feature.get('Shops in area'));
```

It turns out that the .0 is cut-off as well. 
With the percentages it is with 1 or 2 decimals. `22.30` is shown as `22.3` while `16.67`is shown as `16.67`